# C# WPF Data exchange between Page in a Frame and MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

In my MainWindow.xaml i have the following code:

```
<Frame Name="FrmView" Source="Overview.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```

In Overview.xaml.cs now i want to acces an ObservableCollection which is declared and initialized in MainWindow.xaml.cs. Is there any way to gain access to the MainWindow from a Frame/Page ?

Comment: I also have the same problem. Far today I have used Binding, Static classes and static properties. But now i can see that smth isn't in the right way. Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

you could try Window.GetWindow(this) in the page. This should give you the top level window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your application like:

- or a resource present in `application  resource` dictionary, so can be accessed by different
  windows
- or like a code-behind variable and get/set it via code and not from XAML.